# "Unexpected end of input" Javascript registration/login system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am making a project in school and I actually had my "registration and login system" working, but now I get an error in the console, when making a registration. Is it a syntax error? I simply don't know, since I'm completely new to working with localStorage. (This is my first project using localStorage). I could really use some help to clear up how to fix my error.

Cheers.

HTML5

```
<div id="registerDialog" title="Register as user" style="display: none;">
  <input id="txtUserName" type="text" placeholder="User name">
  <input id="txtUserPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password"><br>
  <button id="dialogRegBtn">Register</button>
</div>

<div id="loginDialog" title="Login" style="display: none;">
  <input id="loginUserName" type="text" placeholder="User name">
  <input id="loginUserPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password"><br>
  <button id="dialogLoginBtn">Login</button>
</div>
```

JQUERY AND JAVASCRIPT

```
  $(document).on("click", "#dialogRegBtn", function() {
      var userName = $("#txtUserName").val();
      var userPassword = $("#txtUserPassword").val();
      var aUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.aUsers);
      var oUser = {
          "userName": userName,
          "password": userPassword
      };
      aUsers.push(oUser);
      localStorage.aUsers = JSON.stringify(aUsers);
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#loginBtn", function() {
      $("#loginDialog").dialog();
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#dialogLoginBtn", function() {
      var aUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.aUsers);
      var userName = $("#loginUserName").val();
      var userPassword = $("#loginUserPassword").val();
      var loggedIn = false;

      for (var i = 0; i < aUsers.length; i++) {
          if (aUsers[i].userName == userName && aUsers[i].password == userPassword) {
              loggedIn = true;
          }
      };
      if (loggedIn == true) {
          $("#loginDialog").append("Login was succesful");
      } else {
          $("#loginDialog").append("No user with that login information!");
      }
  });
```

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: The `#dialogLoginBtn` code doesn't check whether there's anything in local storage before trying to parse it.

Comment: When does the error happen, and what line is it happening on?

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for checking this. I have found my own mistake, since I manually should put aUsers and square brackets in the localStorage for my solution to work.

Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the localStorage entry contains anything before trying to parse it. In the code below I default `aUsers` to an empty array if there's nothing in `localStorage.aUsers`.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#dialogRegBtn", function() {
      var userName = $("#txtUserName").val();
      var userPassword = $("#txtUserPassword").val();
      var aUsers = localStorage.aUsers ? JSON.parse(localStorage.aUsers) : [];
      var oUser = {
          "userName": userName,
          "password": userPassword
      };
      aUsers.push(oUser);
      localStorage.aUsers = JSON.stringify(aUsers);
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#loginBtn", function() {
      $("#loginDialog").dialog();
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#dialogLoginBtn", function() {
      var aUsers = localStorage.aUsers ? JSON.parse(localStorage.aUsers) : [];
      var userName = $("#loginUserName").val();
      var userPassword = $("#loginUserPassword").val();
      var loggedIn = false;

      for (var i = 0; i < aUsers.length; i++) {
          if (aUsers[i].userName == userName && aUsers[i].password == userPassword) {
              loggedIn = true;
          }
      };
      if (loggedIn == true) {
          $("#loginDialog").append("Login was succesful");
      } else {
          $("#loginDialog").append("No user with that login information!");
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="registerDialog" title="Register as user">
  <input id="txtUserName" type="text" placeholder="User name">
  <input id="txtUserPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password"><br>
  <button id="dialogRegBtn">Register</button>
</div>

<div id="loginDialog" title="Login">
  <input id="loginUserName" type="text" placeholder="User name">
  <input id="loginUserPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password"><br>
  <button id="dialogLoginBtn">Login</button>
</div>
```